# what can i do to fix this and print out all the names in the tuple that start with the same first letter

Tags: python

```
boys=("david","andrew","ted","tom","james","nicholas","kyle","michael","mark")

startn=()
uname=raw_input("What is your first name?: ")
begin=uname[0]
for name2 in range(len(boys)):
     if begin== boys[name[0]]:
          startn+=(boys[name2],)
          print startn,"start with",begin

     else:
          print "Sorry there are no names that begin with", begin
```

Comment: i try all that it work but when i print it out only m work and other letter like j t a all that doesnt work. i print out name2[0] after the for loop and it print out m what is that happening ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `name[0]` as the index when accessing `boys`. You want to be using `name2`:

```
if begin == boys[name2][0]:
    startn += boys[name2]
```

Alternatively you can just iterate over the `boys` array itself:

```
for boy_name in boys:
    boy_name[0] == begin:
        startn += boy_name
```

(I'm not entirely sure what you're doing with `startn` as you haven't included that bit of your code.)

Answer (score 0):

As a pythonic way for this aim use `str.startswith()` :

```
>>> boys=("david","andrew","ted","tom","james","nicholas","kyle","michael","mark")
>>> boys[1].startswith('a')
True
>>> boys[2].startswith('b')
False
```

So your code must be :

```
boys=("david","andrew","ted","tom","james","nicholas","kyle","michael","mark")

startn=()
uname=raw_input("What is your first name?: ")
for name2 in boys:
     if name2.startswith(uname[0]):
          startn+=(boys[name2],)
          print startn,"start with",begin

     else:
          print "Sorry there are no names that begin with", begin
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can improve here. Let's see how we can clean this up and get it working.

```
for name2 in range(len(boys)):
```

You don't need the `range()` or `len()` call. If you want to iterate over the names, you do that directly with your for-loop.

```
for name in boys:
```

Now inside your loop you have two variables. You have the name entered `uname` and the current name from the loop `name`. You can easily compare the first characters of each by comparing `uname[0]` and `name[0]`

Comment: for name2 in boys:
    if uname[0] == name2[0]:
        startn+=(name2,)
only m work i try J and other letters but it doesnt work